# Understanding relationship between arrays and pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, implicit-conversion

I was recently reading about difference between `T*` and `T[size]`, T being the type, and it make me curious so I was playing around with it.

```
int main()
{
    int a[10];
    using int10arrayPtr_t = int(*)[10];
    int10arrayPtr_t acopy = a;
}
```

In the above code, `int10array_t acopy = a;` is an error with message

```
error C2440: 'initializing': 
cannot convert from 'int [10]' to 'int10array_t'
```

And this compiles:

```
int main()
{
    int a[10];
    using int10arrayPtr_t = int*;
    int10arrayPtr_t acopy = a;
}
```

Isnt the type `int(*)[10]` closer the the type of  `int a[10];` than `int*`? So why does it not allow the first case?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay) may shed some light.

Comment: Your first situation is similar to `int a; using intptr = int*; intptr copy = a;`

Comment: Note that the "_t" suffix is reserved in POSIX and is best avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array designators used in expressions with rare exceptions are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements.

So if you have for example an array

```
T a[N];
```

then you may write

```
T *p = a;
```

because due to the implicit conversion the above declaration is equivalent to

```
T *p = &a[0];
```

If you apply the address of operator & to an array then you get a pointer dereferencing which you will get the original object.

For example

```
T a[N];
T ( *p )[N] = &a;

std::cout << sizeof( *p )  << '\n';
```

the output statement will give the size of the array a.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    using T = int;

    T a[N];

    T *p = a;

    std::cout << "std::is_same_v<T &, decltype( *p )> is "
        << std::boolalpha << std::is_same_v<T &, decltype( *p )>
        << '\n';

    std::cout << "sizeof( *p ) = " << sizeof( *p ) << '\n';

    T( *q )[N] = &a;

    std::cout << "std::is_same_v<T ( & )[N], decltype( *q )> is "
        << std::boolalpha << std::is_same_v<T ( & )[N], decltype( *q )>
        << '\n';

    std::cout << "sizeof( *q ) = " << sizeof( *q ) << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
std::is_same_v<T &, decltype( *p )> is true
sizeof( *p ) = 4
std::is_same_v<T ( & )[N], decltype( *q )> is true
sizeof( *q ) = 40
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In line `T ( *p )[N] = &a;` how come `&a` gives you the pointer to array when a is already a pointer to the array. In my mind, a is already a pointer to array. `&a` would give you pointer to pointer to array, but this is obviously not the case as demonstrated by your answer.

Comment: @fbiopen_up In this case a is not converted to a pointer to its first element when the operator & is used. Also an array is not converted to a pointer when is used as an operand of the sizeof operator. Compare: int a[10];  sizeof( a ) and sizeof( a + 0 ). In the second case a indeed converted to a pointer in the expression a + 0.

Answer (score 4):

You need to take the address explicitly, e.g.

```
int10arrayPtr_t acopy = &a; // acopy is a pointer to array containing 10 ints
//                      ^
```

The 2nd case works because array could [decay](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array-to-pointer_decay) to pointer, for `a`, it could convert to `int*` implicitly, and `acopy` is a pointer to `int` (note that it's not a pointer to array).

Answer (score 3):

In your first example, the symbol `int10arrayPtr_t` is an alias for a "pointer to an array of `10` integers". In your second example the same symbol is an alias for "pointer to a *single integer*". That's quite a different thing.

Also, it's true that arrays decays to pointers to their first element, but it's a pointer to a single element of the array. I.e. plain `a` will decay to `&a[0]`, which have the type `int*`. To get a pointer to the array you need to use the pointer-to operator `&` for the whole array, as in `&a`.